# Why would invoking this method cause my app to go over the free quota?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

Having trouble understanding what is going on. The only location I call datastore.Put operations (no indexes as far as I can tell) is in the function below. It is called exactly  9 times per minute (or less if something fails).

```
func SaveCurrentStatus(c appengine.Context, check *StatusCheck, ok bool, latency time.Duration, message string) {
    r := Result{
        Id:      check.Id,
        Name:    check.Name,
        Ok:      ok,
        Latency: latency,
        Message: message,
    }
    uid := datastore.NewKey(c, "Status", "", check.Id, nil)
    _, err := datastore.Put(c, uid, &r)
    if err != nil {
        c.Errorf("%s", err.Error())
        return
    }

    MemcachePut(c, fmt.Sprintf("Status-%d", check.Id), r)
}
```

It is my understanding that this should result in 9*60*24 write operations (they are not new entities). This is a total of 19,960 operations per day, the free quota is supposed to be 0.05 million?

Are there any utilities that might help me analyse what is going on or see some sort of log of what is going on that I don't know about?

Comment: configure appstats and check the RPC calls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not have much experience with Go but I would say that you must explicitly set your properties to be unindexed otherwise they are indexed by default. Then each entity write also includes writes to every index (both ascendent and descendent) associated with the entity's properties.

You can find more details [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/indexes#Go_Unindexed_properties).

In [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/) you can check which properties of a given entity use index.

Go to the Storage / Cloud Datastore / Dashboard and as a kind select entity of your choice.  It displays all properties along with their index size.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, unfortunately the "Cloud datastore" -> "Dashboard" indicates there are no indexes.

Comment: It means that column displaying index size is empty, right? And do you set your properties to be unindexed explicitly?